# ASP.NET Core send nested list from razor view page to controller action is null?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, viewmodel, model-binding, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am trying to send a sub list called `OrderItems` [`EditOrderViewModel`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKLDt.jpg) from a razor view page [view page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/My5Ek.jpg) to controller action [Post Action method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPLyT.jpg) but I always get null for the `OrderItem` [Edit action post method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5RC1.jpg) sub list and [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1fgR.jpg) shows the inspected form fields. any help? note that I am using JQuery Ajax to send the data using form .serialize() method and [this is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUu94.jpg) the data that it sends.

Comment: instead of posting screenshots of code, you should post code directly in your question, the chance of getting help will be increased. Otherwise no one would want to care about your issue.

Comment: that's for your benefit, another reason is for community's benefit, by posting code directly (text data), the search engines can index and help others find your question & the answers to it, which can help them solve their similar issues.

Comment: The model binding bind the model by the name of the inputs,I could see your code added the name with correct name(`[i].Code`) but why do they render the name is like:`group-a[1][1]`,they are different and it seems to be impossible?This is why you receive null in backend.Please share the code instead of picture,maybe your code contains other things.

Comment: thank you for responding and giving suggestions, Finally, I found the problem. It was giving the wrong name because of a Jquery plugin called Form repeater. This plugin has added group-a as a prefix to the input names.